# CONVERT Date INT to DATE in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause

How can I convert a date integer to a date type? (20200531 into 5/31/2020)

My current table has a datadate formatted as YYYYMMDD (20200531, 20200430, etc.)

The Datatype for the datadate is an int according the Toad Data Point software I'm using.  I believe it's using ORACLE sql database.

As a result, when querying this data, I have to type in the where clause as below..

```
where datadate = '20200531'
```

My goal is to convert this integer datadate into a date format (5/31/2020) so I can apply the datadate to the where clause.

like..

```
WHERE datadate = dateadd(DD, -1, CAST(getdate() as date))
```

Comment: specify which sql?

Comment: When you say “dataset” do you mean a SQL table? Tell us the `datadate` type.

Comment: "date integers" are not what you think they are. What you have a formatted date in a `string`. An actual integer-date would be a UNIX timestamp value.

Comment: Please confirm the exact **data-type** (not "date-type") of the `datadate` column. Is it really a `char`/`varchar`/`nchar`/`nvarchar` column?

Comment: dates as ints do have some limited purpose. They are far better than varchar. Of course the correct datatype is date. You'll need to specify what type of database this is - Oracle? SQL?

Comment: `dateadd` is not an Oracle function. I suggest you run `SELECT * FROM v$version;` to confirm if this is Oracle. Please be certain about the information you provide. If your'e not sure, find out.

Comment: Two observations:  First, your statement "I _believe_ it's using ORACLE sql database." (emphasis mine).  It is imperative that you _know_ what database you are dealing with, as any and all possible solutions will depend on that.  Second, it is equally imperative to _know_ exactly what data type the column is.  And if it is _anything_ besides DATE (in oracle, or the equivelent in other databases), then you have a very serious design flaw.

Comment: @EdStevens You're right about the design flaw and after providing clarity, i don't think its an oracle sql database.   I'm using the SQL editor provided by Quest Toad Datapoint.  Not sure what type of sql that is..

Comment: Toad Data Point is just a reporting tool. It can connect to, and report from, any number of databases ....  Saying you think your database is Oracle because you are using a particular reporting tool is like saying you think you are calling the govenor of New Jersey because you have an iPhone.  Surely you have some sort of support person who can _confirm_ the database and the data type.  Until you _confirm_ the database _and_ the data type of the column, everything is just conjecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Read below for my answer for if it's an `int` column)

### Assuming it's a textual string:

Assuming that `datadate` is a string (character, text, etc) column and not a `date`/`datetime`/`datetime2`/`datetimeoffset` column, then use the `CONVERT` function with `style: 23`. The `23` value corresponds to ISO 8601 because the values are in `yyyy-MM-dd`-order, even though they're missing dashes.

This page has a reference of `style` numbers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            myTable.*
            CONVERT( date, datadate, 23 ) AS valueAsDate
        FROM
            myTable
    ) AS q
WHERE
    q.valueAsDate = DATEADD( dd, -1, GETDATE() )
```

### Assuming it's an actual `int` column:

The quick-and-dirty way is to convert the `int` to `varchar` and then use the same code as above as if it were a textual field - but **don't do this** because it's slow:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            myTable.*,
            CONVERT( char(8), datadate ) AS valueAsChar,
            CONVERT( date, CONVERT( char(8), datadate ), 23 ) AS valueAsDate
        FROM
            myTable
    ) AS q
WHERE
    q.valueAsDate = DATEADD( dd, -1, GETDATE() )
```

### Assuming it's an actual `int` column (better answer):

(I extend my gratitude to [@alain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529618/alain) for pointing out a rather egregious error in my arithmetic and providing a better solution)

We'll need to use `DATEFROMPARTS` and extract each component using Base-10 arithmetic (*fun*)!

Supposing we have an integer representing a formatted date <sub>(the horror)</sub> such as `20200531` then we need to use *integer*-only arithmetic, [such that division truncates rather than rounds](https://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/%7Epa/f90Notes/HTMLNotesnode87.html#:%7E:text=Confusion%20often%20arises%20about%20integer,by%20truncation%20(towards%20zero).&text=a%20is%20(about)%201.000.,to%20produce%20an%20integral%20value.) - so dividing by 10000, we get `2020`, then multiply back to get `20200000`:

```
20200531 /    10000 =>      2020
    2020 *    10000 =>  20200000
20200531 - 20200000 =>       531
     531 /      100 =>         5
       5 *      100 =>       500
     531 -      500 =>        31
```

Or:

```
datadate /    10000 =>      yyyy
    yyyy *    10000 =>  yyyy0000
datadate - yyyy0000 =>      MMdd
    MMdd /      100 =>        MM
      MM *      100 =>      MM00
    MMdd -     MM00 =>        dd
```

...which reduces down to:

```
yyyy = ( datadate / 10000 )
  MM = ( datadate - ( yyyy * 10000 ) ) / 100
  dd = ( ( datadate - ( yyyy * 10000 ) ) - ( ( MM ) * 100 ) )
```

...which can be converted into a T-SQL scalar UDF:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UnhorriblifyDate( @date int )
RETURNS date
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @yyyy int = @date / 10000;
    DECLARE @mm   int = ( @date - ( @yyyy * 10000 ) ) / 100;
    DECLARE @dd   int = ( ( @date - ( @yyyy * 10000 ) ) - ( ( @mm ) * 100 ) );
    
    DECLARE @result date = DATEFROMPARTS( @yyyy, @mm, @dd );
    RETURN @result;
END
```

Or in a query:

```
WITH dateParts AS (

SELECT
    c.datadata,
    c.yyyy,
    c.mm,
    ( ( c.datadate - ( c.yyyy * 10000 ) ) - ( ( c.MM ) * 100 ) ) AS dd
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            b.datadata,
            b.yyyy,
            ( b.datadate - ( b.yyyy * 10000 ) ) / 100 AS mm
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    a.datadata,
                    a.datadate / 10000 AS yyyy
                FROM
                    myTable AS a
            ) AS b
    ) AS c
)
SELECT
    c.datadata,
    DATEFROMPARTS( d.yyyy, d.mm, d.dd ) AS valueAsDate
FROM
    dateParts AS d;
```

Comment: The MOD 31 approach is wrong. For example, `20200101 % 31` is `5` - when the "day" we're looking for here is `1`.  If you'd tested the example you gave, you would also see the result is incorrect: `19950707 mod 31` returns 6, not 7. You should instead be doing `datadate - (datadate / 100)` to get the day part.

Comment: @Alain Thank you for the feedback - would you be okay with editing my post to correct that error?

Comment: Correction: `datadate - (datadate / 100) * 100` - and depending on your choice of database engine, you might need to "force" integer division with a cast or something - some engines may switch automatically to decimal division.

Comment: @Alain I've reworked my post - I'd appreciate it if you could take a look and share your thoughts

Comment: Good update @Dai. It's well derived, and correct now, but note that you can simplify things a bit further for MM and DD: `SELECT (datadate/10000) AS YEAR, (datadate/100-100*(datadate/10000)) AS MONTH, (datadate-100*(datadate/100)) AS DAY`

Answer (score 0):

This answers assumes that you are running Oracle, as suggested in your question.

> How can I convert a date integer to a date type? (20200531 into 5/31/2020)

In Oracle, you use `to_date()` to convert a string to a number. If you are giving it a number, it implicitly converts it to a string before converting it. So in both cases, you would do:

```
to_date(datadate, 'yyyymmdd')
```

> My goal is to convert this integer datadate into a date format (5/31/2020) so I can apply the datadate to the where clause.

Generally, you want to avoid applying a function on a column in a `where` predicate: it is not efficient, because the database needs to apply the function on the entire column *before* it is able to filter. If you want to filter on `dateadd` as of yesterday, then I would recommend computing yesterday's date and putting it in the same format as the column that is filtered, so you can do a direct match against the existing column values.

If your column is a string:

```
where datadatea = to_char(sysdate - 1, 'yyyymmdd')
```

If it's a number:

```
where datadatea = to_number(to_char(sysdate - 1, 'yyyymmdd'))
```